# Prove that $\text{Dom}(f)\in \wp(\cup(\cup(f)))$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that $$\text{Dom}(f)\in \wp (\cup(\cup(f)))$$ Where $f$ is a function and $\cup$ is a union and $\wp$ stands for powerset. I searched for a long time, and couldn't find anything. Any ideas on how to start?

Comment: What is $f$, what is $U(f)$, what is..., and so on. At least you should make clear what you are talking about.

Comment: @drhab f is a function, I thought it is clear because of the domain()... also U is for union. I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the few cases where the details of the Kuratowski definition of ordered pairs are relevant.

Remember that according to Kuratowski, $\langle a,b\rangle$ is an abbreviation for $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, so in particular $a$ is an element of an element of $\langle a,b\rangle$.

Furthermore, if $\langle a,b\rangle \in f$, this means that $a$ is an element of an element of an element of $f$ -- thus, two unions will give you all the first elements (and probably other stuff too that we don't care about for the time being, such as all the second elements). That is,

$$ \operatorname{Dom} f \subseteq \cup ( \cup f ) $$

---

Note that this is **not** necessarily true if you use another definition of ordered pairs than the Kuratowski one -- for example, it is not true for [Quine's type-level definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Quine.E2.80.93Rosser_definition)